# Is it possible to localize the NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription string displayed by the iOS 14 "Select More" dialog?

Tags: ios14, ios-permissions

My iOS project is set up with localized permission dialog text, through **using the InfoPlist.strings file** and checking it into my build target.

On iOS 14, when requesting for Photos library permissions, I noticed that the first time the app requests for this permission, the popup (containing 3 options: Select photos, Allow all photos, Deny) will have its permission text **correctly translated** as per the InfoPlist.strings file.

However, from the next time the app requests for this permission, the popup (which contains 2 options: Select more photos, Use current selection) will *not* have its permission text translated.

I've also found a [Apple Developer forum question](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/663802) raising the same issue, and the answer from Apple Support Staff doesn't seem to help, as my project is already using the InfoPlist.strings file, and the permission text is indeed translated on the first-time popup.

Are there some steps that I'm missing in my setup, or is this a known issue on iOS 14?

Comment: same problem, do you have any solution for it?